# "Date created" on hard drive; cloned?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, data-transfer, data-recovery

Can I tell whether my hard drive has been cloned? I had a repair done and do not know what they performed on the computer; they may have replaced my hard drive with the same model and cloned my information to it- I am not entirely sure if they did this. I have a Macbook Pro, 2012 model.

I read online somewhere that the Volume Creation date, or "date created" would update to the time when the clone was done- basically when the volume was created on that new drive. All other information would be identical. Is this one way to tell...? Please let me know. Thanks all!

Comment: are you saying they gave you new drive and will not tell you about it ?

Comment: They don't know and they can't because they made no record of the repair... I really just did not have a good experience with them and would like to see if this did in fact happen.

Comment: try the simple way, open the Activity Monitor > Disk and look at bottom right, for Data read and data written. Tell me that number.

Comment: Data read: 1.36 GB
Data written: 349 MB.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this number resets afters powering off :(

Answer (score 1):

On your Mac, you can use Terminal to see the amount of data you've written to your drive.

Open Terminal and enter the "`diskutil list`" command.

Find your physical drive on the list, which includes partitions and virtual disks. In my case, my physical is `disk0`.

It is usually disk0.

Enter this command: "`iostat -Id disk0`" or similar (depending on the number for your drive).

You will see three values listed:

```
KB/t = kilobytes per transfer
xfrs = number of transfers
MB = number of megabytes transferred
```

The value listed under MB is the total number of megabytes that you have written to your drive from when **it was first installed to now**.

In your case been 2012 model I suspect somewhere around 500GB (500,000MB) to 1000GB...or more.

Comment: Would this number be different if the drive was wiped /reinstalled?

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would be @GrownShades

Comment: Now if it was an already used disk, you may not be able to tell the difference

Comment: A wipe and reinstall was done in 2016 - my values are 71.86 KN/t, xfrs is 550k and MB is 38k.

Comment: That’s odd - the values change/ increase every time I type in the code. Now it’s at 74k MB

Comment: I'd say that it's a new disk

Comment: It’s at 200K now. The drive date is from 2012 though, with 14k Power on Hours?